# laravel code to redirect back to main page after a successful login message

Tags: laravel

```
if($res){
    return back()->with('success','You have signed in successful');

    //this code is not working//
    return redirect()->route('welcome');
} else {
    return back()->with('fail','something went wrong');
}
```

Comment: `return redirect()->route('welcome');` doesn't work because you already `return` in the live above

Comment: ok thanks, so how should I do it? i tried removing the first return but the login message didnt show up

Comment: Stab in the dark: `return redirect()->route('welcome')->with('success','You have signed in successful')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t have 2 return in same block, the second never will be called.

If want go to the next view u should delete the first return:

```
if($res){
    return redirect()->route('welcome');
} else {
    return back()->with('fail','something went wrong');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if($res){
    return back()->with('success','You have signed in successful');

    //this code is not working//
    return redirect()->route('welcome');
} else {
    return back()->with('fail','something went wrong');
}
```

Write:

```
if($res){
    return redirect(route('welcome'))->with('success','You have signed in successful');
} else {
    return redirect()->back()->with('fail','something went wrong');
}
```

You cant use two returns after each other. So just send the success message with the return at once.

Comment: Ok so the route worked successfully but the success message wasn't displayed

Comment: How do you display it in your view?

Comment: @if(Session::has('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('success')}}</div>
                @endif

Comment: Try `@if(session('success')) {{ session('success') }} @endif `

Comment: With your div it would look like: `@if(session('success')) <div class="alert alert-success">{{ session('success') }}</div> @endif`

Answer (score 0):

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->withSuccess('You have Successfully loggedin');
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).